# Entity Framework Core 2 querying multi level collections with theniclude

Tags: include, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

I created two classes:

```
public class A {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B {
  public ICollection<C> C1s { get; set; }
  public ICollection<C> C2s { get; set; }
}
```

then I tried to fetch them with ThenInclude method:

```
var result = context.As          //public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
  .Include(a => a.Bs)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.C1s)
  .Include(a => a.Bs)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.C2s)
  .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id.Equals(id)); //id is given

return await result;
```

But unfortunately both C1s and C2s collections are empty.

How to retrieve C entities which are related to B one?

Comment: But C1s and C2s are empty after execute await command. I will edit a post and add await in a code to show where it is, but I think it does not matter here.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced .ThenInclude() methods with

```
.Include("Points.MasterPoints")
.Include("Points.SlavePoints")
```

That solved my issue.